# Getting error while migrating the models using Django and python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need one help. I am getting the below error while migrating the model file using Python and Django. I am explaining the errors below.

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/carClinic/carClinic/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 280, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 264, in get_urls
    url(r'^%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
AttributeError: 'Personal' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

I am explaining my code below.

> models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from datetime import datetime

class Service(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for service table has declared"""
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_service = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    vechile_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Personal(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for Person table has declared"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    driving_license = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

admin.site.register(Service, Personal)
```

> urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here I need to display both classes inside admin panels. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: please check again. I updated the post.

Comment: have you written anything in the admin.py of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
admin.site.register(Service, Personal)
```

The second parameter to the above call should  be a ModelAdmin subclass but you are passing the Personal model instead. Which naturally does not have the urls property.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.register):

> AdminSite.register(model_or_iterable, admin_class=None,
>   **options)
>   Registers the given model class (or iterable of classes) with the given admin_class. admin_class defaults to ModelAdmin

Code like this should anyway be placed in admin.py according to convention rather than models.py and it should look like

```
admin.site.register(Personal)
admin.site.register(Service)
```

If you wanted to use your own custom ModelAdmin

```
class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_fields = ['cname','date_of_service']

admin.site.register(Service, ServiceAdmin)
```